# keep getting error when running bot2.js

Tags: json, node.js, nodes, steam, steambot

I'm new to this and I don't understand what it says in this error

When I type, node bot2.js

I get this error message:

```
ReferenceError: bot2 is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
    at bound (domain.js:291:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:304:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
```

Can anyone please translate this for me or explain what I'm doing wrong or if I need to download something?

Thanks